# Filtering out IDs that contain a certain value in another column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

So I am trying to filter out IDs from these 2 tables I 'union all'ed. Basically if the ID contains a certain name, I want to filter them out of the query. Here is an example

```
ID,Name

1,Mark  
1,John  
2,Peter  
2,Matt  
3,Henry  
3,Matt  
4,John  
4,Olaf
```

So I do not want to include IDs that contain 'Matt' meaning I would like to filter out IDs 2 and 3 out completely.

using something like:

```
select *  
from name.table  
where name not like 'Matt'
```

only seems to filter out the row.

Comment: `trying to filter out IDs from these 2 tables`? Where is the other one?

Comment: This is the result of the union all, hence why you see duplicate IDs with different names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would want to do something like this:

```
select * from table where id not in(
   select Id from table where name like '%Matt%'
)
```

This excludes rows with name containing Matt

Exclude rows that equal Matt

```
select * from table where id not in(
   select Id from table where name ='Matt'
)
```

Comment: Hey, your first one worked perfectly for me! Thank you so much!.

Answer (score 1):

Use `not exists`:

```
select n.*
from names n
where not exists (select 1 from names n2 where n2.id = n.id and n2.name = 'Matt')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM TableName
WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM TableName WHERE name='Matt')
```

**OR** Using `LIKE`:

```
SELECT * FROM TableName
WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM TableName WHERE name LIKE '%Matt%')
```

**For distinct values:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM TableName
WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM TableName WHERE name='Matt')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM names
WHERE ID NOT IN
(SELECT ID FROM names WHERE name='Matt')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(SELECT Column(s) FROM Table1)
UNION ALL
(SELECT Column(s) FROM Table2)
EXCEPT
(SELECT Column(s) FROM Table1 where name = 'Matt')
EXCEPT
(SELECT Column(s) FROM Table2 where name = 'Matt')
```